# Is it possible to have dynamically generated query names in ColdFusion?

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-9, cfquery

What I am trying to do is

```
<cfloop array="#LOCAL.someArray" index="LOCAL.aString">

    <cfset LOCAL.queryName = "uniqueQueryName_" & LOCAL.aString />

    <cfquery name="#LOCAL.queryName#" datasource="db" cachedwithin="#CreateTimeSpan(1,0,0,0)#">
        SELECT count(*) AS c FROM someTable
    </cfquery>

    <cfdump var="#LOCAL.queryName#" />
</cfloop>
```

is this possible, or is there a better way to do it?

**Edit**

This works with `<cfloop query="LOCAL.queryName">` but not when I try to do `<cfset ArrayAppend(LOCAL.returnArray, LOCAL.queryName.c) />`

Comment: Did you try to do it? Are you getting any errors?

Comment: When I run it `<cfdump>` just puts out the string value of the name, `uniqueQueryName_foo`, `uniqueQueryName_bar`, etc.

Comment: To access a query row dynamically, use associative array notation ie `Local["nameOfQuery"]["theColumnName"][rowNumber]`

Comment: ahhh yes scopes are treaded as structs in CF, I had forgotten about that, good call.

Comment: @Leigh, do you put answers in the comments to give others the opportunity for points, because that is definitely the right answer.

Comment: @JamesRLamar - Sometimes yeah, or when I do not have time to write up a solid (tested) answer.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There is no need to use `evaluate()` to do this, and one shouldn't (so I've down-voted that answer, sorry).

All you need to do is use associative array notation:

```
<cfdump var="#local[qname]#">
```

If one wants to access a column of that query, it's:

```
#local[qname][columnName]#
```

And for a specific cell:

```
#local[qname][columnName][rowNumber]#
```

There are very very very few situations in which `evaluate()` is the correct answer to anything.  One cannot rely on the Adobe docs because - unfortunately - an awful lot of it was not written by very experienced ColdFusion developers.

Comment: Have you actually tested it? Regardless which combination of pound signs I use I can only get that method to work with `<cfdump>`, which isn't very useful.

Comment: @johnthexiii - It works fine. I suspect the problem is your original code puts the query in the `variables` scope, not `local`. Your query declaration should be more like: `<cfquery name="LOCAL.#someDynamicNameHere#" ..>`

Comment: I wasn't suggesting it was copy & paste & it works code: it was just demonstrating the syntax (and, yes, it does work).  I have to concede I was presuming you were local-scoping your variables, as per your initial example.

Comment: I would suggest not leaving the query floating in the variable scope to start with. Just create a structure to hold it and any other related data.

Answer (score 0):

You can dump the query, and I imagine also access it by doing something like this:

```
<cfloop list="q1,q2,q3" index="qname">


    <cfquery name="#qname#" datasource="dsn">
        SELECT * from some_table;
    </cfquery>

    <cfdump var="#Evaluate('#qname#')#" />
</cfloop>
```

The [Evaluate](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/CFMLRef/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec22c24-7f4e.html) function is what allows you to do what you want.

Comment: This is working, Adobe even uses Evaluate with a query in their docs.

Comment: Don't trust the examples in Adobe's docs - unfortunately they're not always sensible.

Comment: @johnthexiii - Never assume the snippets in the docs are always examples of good coding practices. They are just for demonstration and do not always use best practices. Typically `evaluate` is discouraged. Primarily because it is rarely needed, but it can also pose security risks in some situations. In your code, it is not needed. Just use associative array notation.